# Crear un select de html usando ajax

Tags: javascript, html, ajax

Tengo el siguiente código html

```
                            <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6">
                                <label class="col-sm-3 control-label no-padding-right" for="form-field-1"> Beneficiarios </label>
                                <div class="col-sm-7">
                                    <select name="SociosPosibles" id="SociosPosibles" class="form-control mandatory" title="Socios Posibles" required>
                                        <option value=""></option>

                                    </select>
                                </div>
                            </div>
```

y el select lo lleno con un ajax pero siempre me sale error
$.ajax({
url: 'includes/async/reportetalonera.async.php',
type: 'POST',
dataType: 'json',

```
                    data: ({
                            'oper': 'ConsulIdSocio',
                            'idSocio': suggestion.data,

                        })

                        ,
                    beforeSend: function() {
                        console.log('enviando datos al servidor para consultar beneficiarios');
                    }
                })
                .done(function(data) {
                    console.log('success');
                    console.log(data);
                    $.each(data, function(key, registro) {

                        $("#SociosPosibles").append('<option value=' + registro.idsocio + '>' + registro.nombre + '</option>');
                    });

                })
                .fail(function(resp) {
                    console.log('error');
                    console.log(resp.responseText);
                })
                .always(function() {
                    // console.log('Complete');
                })
```

el json que me trae la consulta es el siguiente
[{"idsocio":"5533","nombre":"Jorge armando"}]

Comment: Que error le tira?  A propósito, si PHP le regresa JSON, hay que llamar  JSON.parse(data) y usar el resultado.

Answer (score 0):

Como dice el comentario, debes usar **JSON.parse** para manipular la data

Te dejo un ejemplo que puedes usar más sencillo:

```
 var parametros="oper=ConsulIdSocio&idSocio="+suggestion.data;
     $.ajax({
            data:  parametros, 
            url:   'includes/async/reportetalonera.async.php', 
            type:  'POST',
            beforeSend: function(){
            },
            success:  function (response) 
             {
                var data=JSON.parse(response);
                $.each(data,function()
                    {
                         $("#SociosPosibles").append('<option value="'+this.idsocio+'">'+this.nombre+'</option>');
                    });
             }
        });
```

Probe en mi local con la data que me diste:

*[{"idsocio":"5533","nombre":"Jorge armando"}]*